# Image quality of pdf file generated from latex

Tags: pdftex, pdf

I have been using my computer to generating pdf files from latex file by Winshell (or lyx), but the characters (or images) in the pdf files generated on my computer looks always much worse than the pdf files other people generate on their computers. Could anyone tell me what the problem is, or how to improve the quality of pdf file to be generated on the my computer? (I am using the newest version of Adobe Reader, and the miktek files are almost complete.)

Comment: Could you post a minimal example that you're trying to compile with pdflatex, in particular which packages are you loading. The version of your TeX distribution is also probably relevant.

Comment: Winshell and Lyx do not generate PDFs. pdfLaTeX does this. Tell us (1) what version of MikTeX, (2) what fonts, font encoding and versions, (3) if it looks bad when printed or just on screen, (4) if the answer to (2) is Computer Modern, whether cm-super is installed.

Comment: (1) MiKTeX 2.7
(2)\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
(3) I think both on screen and print out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `\usepackage{lmodern}`. When you switch to the `T1` encoding, the only available fonts (I assume) for your distribution are the bitmap Computer Modern fonts (caveat: I'm simplifying). Loading the Latin Modern fonts will fix that — they are largely identical in appearance.

Comment: Will, Thanks a lot! I can get better image by using the package you suggested.

Answer (score 3):

[This FAQ answer](http://texfaq.org/FAQ-dvips-pdf) discusses a number of reasons why the PDF quality may suffer.

The [testflow](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/testflow) package can also help with diagnosing such problems.

If you post a [small example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) of latex you are compiling and you also put resulting PDF online somewhere ([drop.io](http://drop.io) for example) then we can probably help further.