# Bitmap font in bbold package

Tags: bitmap

I'm getting a bitmap font on `\mathbb{1}` when I use the `bbold` package. After much searching on bitmap fonts specifically in relation to the `bbold` package, these articles are the closest I've got to a solution:

[\mathbb{Z} is not displayed correctly](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3523/mathbbz-is-not-displayed-correctly)

[Image quality of pdf file generated from latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2530/image-quality-of-pdf-file-generated-from-latex)

However, they don't quite answer my problem. The best advice in the first is to use `amssymb`, which doesn't work in my particular case because `amssymb` renders `\mathbb{1}` as something else entirely (not a blackboard "1"). The second article is a bit general but does suggest the `lmodern` package, which still doesn't solve the problem.

Note also that I've already installed the cm-super font (using MiKTeX), as many other articles suggest.

Here's my code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{bbold}

\begin{document}

This is a test: $\mathbb{1}$.

\end{document}
```

Here's a fragment (the important bit) of the output:

[image: Bitmap font on \mathbb{1}]

As the image shows, only the `\mathbb{1}` is a problem.

Comment: Install `bbold-type1`: http://miktex.org/packages/bbold-type1

Comment: Thanks for that. Though I should have explained that I've already installed that font (both the standard version and the type-1 version).

Comment: Run `updmap`, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33608/how-to-run-updmap-sys-after-installing-cm-super

Comment: That worked, thank you. I assumed refreshing the FNDB was enough after any install on MiKTeX—I didn't realize fonts required something else.

Comment: I've seen several times this problem reported: MiKTeX doesn't update the font maps after installing font packages.